# GCC Warning: pointer arithmetic with type void *

Tags: c, linux, gcc, void-pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I have to write a function, in C on Linux, to read or write generic data.

I can read (or write) big data so i made a while using how many bytes I read.
At the next call i, for example, read in the original pointer + how many bytes I read. But I don't know the type so I used a void * but gcc says:

```
membox.c: In function ‘myRW’:
membox.c:301:22: warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
w = read(fd, data + (s*type) , len - s);
                  ^
membox.c:308:23: warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
w = write(fd, data + (s*type) , len - s);
```

Can i do this? I should ignore this warnings?

Comment: `char*` is probably the pointer type you want for arithmetic.

Comment: OT: Those `long int`s should as well be `size_t`s.

Comment: OT^2: By convention on error `-1` is returned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cast the `void *` to `char *`.  That way, you have an underlying type of size 1 to do pointer arithmetic on.

```
(char*)data + (s*type)
```